# Joomla 3.9 Не появляется сообщение

Tags: joomla, email, регистрация, joomla3

нужна помощь по Joomla 3.9. При регистрации пользователя на сайте, если введенный им email уже используется другим пользователем, должно было выходить сообщение о том, что такая почта уже используется. Но никакого сообщения нет и страница просто обновляется. До этого сайт был на Joomla 3.6, но для создания личного кабинета обновили до 3.9. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В данном контексте - проблема может быть в чем угодно. Что уже проверили? Возможно затерлись шаблоны или используется другой шаблон для регистрации.

Comment: меняла версии php с 5.6 на 7.2, вроде никакого эффекта нет. Поискала в интернете там говорили про JLIB_DATABASE_ERROR_EMAIL_INUSE, нашла его в файле EmailRule.php и пыталась там добавить сообщение, чтобы хотя бы проверить. Но тоже ничего не получилось. Шаблон для регистрации не меняла.

Comment: но правки делала в файле registration.php кажется, для перехода на определенные страницы после регистрации и верификации- ссылки меняла. Но даже до этого сообщения не выходили

Answer (score 1):

Нашла ответ. Нужно было лишь добавить

`<jdoc:include type="message" />`